# How can I store a function reference in Swift 2?

Tags: swift, lambda, swift2, react-native

The root problem is that `SkPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment()` doesn't allow you to pass a callback function, and there's no way to pass in a function at runtime (that I know of) to the `SKPaymentTransactionObserver`. I'm using React-native version `0.28` to create a module that allows me to make in-app purchases, however I wanted to callback a Javascript function once the in-app purchase is completed.

Therefore, I was going to store a reference to the `RCTResponseSenderBlock` callback in a class and reference it in `SKPaymentTransactionObserver`. However, I don't know how to refer to a function in Swift.

I've tried making the following variable

`weak var purchaseCallback: RCTResponseSenderBlock = nil`

at the top of the class so I can set it and refer to it later; however, Swift is complaining with the following:

`Nil cannot initialize specified type 'RCTResponseSenderBlock'`

If there is a way to handle function references and/or a better way to make a purchase callback, I'd appreciate some help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Bryan Chen noted in his comment above, making the variable optional did the trick.

Here's how I define the variable that holds the callback:

```
var purchaseCallback: RCTResponseSenderBlock? = nil
```

And here's how I store the function reference from a function called by React-native in Swift:

```
@objc func purchaseProduct(identifier: String, callback successCallback: RCTResponseSenderBlock) {
  purchaseCallback = successCallback
}
```